# SQL Server 2005 Backup File Deletion

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

I wanted to reduce the size of my log file in SQL SERVER 2005, which grown to 16 gigs, so I created a backup and used the dbcc shrinkfile command to shrink it. All that is set. Now what should I do with the backup file that is created - should I delete it? What impact will deletion have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the file will mean you will not be able to do point-in-time restoration - you will only be able to restore to the last database backup you made.

If point-in-time restores are unimportant to you, you can safely delete the backup - otherwise store it somewhere safe (like a tape, or other removable storage).

If you're not using anything that requires a transaction log (e.g. database mirroring) you could also consider switching the database into "simple recovery mode" which avoids transaction log use anyway.

Comment: THANKS JASON,
MY USE OF THE DATABASE IS TO DO FRONT-END REPORTING FOR EXPERIMENTAL INNOVATIONS AND THE DATABASE MOSTLY CONTAINS DUMMY DATA WHICH I MIGHT NOT REFER IN THE FUTURE. SO I GUESS DELETING THE BACKUP FILE WONT HARM ME. :-). 

THANKS AGAIN.